# SwiftUI How to Make Page TabView Dynamic

Tags: swiftui

So I am trying to make my TabView height dynamic. I have been looking for a way to do this but I can't seem to find a solution anywhere. This is how my code looks like.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var contentHeight: CGFloat = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ScrollView {
                VStack {
                    TabView {
                        TestView1(contentHeight: $contentHeight)
                        
                        TestView2(contentHeight: $contentHeight)
                    }
                    .tabViewStyle(.page)
                    .frame(height: contentHeight)
                    .indexViewStyle(.page(backgroundDisplayMode: .always))
                    .background(.yellow)
                }
                
                .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
                .navigationTitle("Test Project")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is how my test1view and test2view look like.

```
struct TestView1: View {
    @State var height: CGFloat = 0
    @Binding var  contentHeight: CGFloat
    
    var body: some View {
        Color.red
            .frame(maxWidth:.infinity, minHeight: 200, maxHeight: 200)
        
            .background(
                GeometryReader { geo in
                    Color.clear
                        .preference(
                            key: HeightPreferenceKey.self,
                            value: geo.size.height
                        )
                        .onAppear {
                            contentHeight = height
                        }
                }
                    .onPreferenceChange(HeightPreferenceKey.self) { height in
                        self.height = height
                    }
            )
    }
}


struct TestView2: View {
    @Binding var  contentHeight: CGFloat
    @State var height: CGFloat = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        Color.black
            .frame(maxWidth:.infinity, minHeight: 350, maxHeight: 350)
            .background(
                GeometryReader { geo in
                    Color.clear
                        .preference(
                            key: HeightPreferenceKey.self,
                            value: geo.size.height
                        )
                        .onAppear {
                            contentHeight = height
                        }
                }
                    .onPreferenceChange(HeightPreferenceKey.self) { height in
                        self.height = height
                    }
            )
    }
}

struct HeightPreferenceKey: PreferenceKey {
    static let defaultValue: CGFloat = 0
    
    static func reduce(value: inout CGFloat, nextValue: () -> CGFloat) {
        value = nextValue()
    }
}
```

Now the problem is that when I drag it just a little the height changes. So when I drag it a little to the left the height changes to the height of TestView2 and it is still on TestView1.

I tried to add a drag gesture but it didn't let me swipe to the next page. So I don't know how I will be able to achieve this. Ive been looking for a solution but still no luck.

Comment: Not really sure what do you expect to achieve. Could you elaborate more?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `TabView($selection)` initializer to do this. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/tabview/init(selection:content:)

It tells you which tab you're currently viewing. Based off the middle point of the screen. And you don't have to deal with nasty `GeometryReader` and `HeightPreferenceKey`.

Here's your updated code. I even added a nice animation to fade between the two heights!

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var selectedTab: Tab = .first
    @State var animatedContentHeight: CGFloat = 300
    
    enum Tab {
        case first
        case second
        
        var contentHeight: CGFloat {
            switch self {
            case .first:
                return 200
            case .second:
                return 350
            }
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $selectedTab) {
            TestView1()
                .tag(Tab.first)
            TestView2()
                .tag(Tab.second)
        }
        .tabViewStyle(.page)
//        .frame(height: selectedTab.contentHeight) // Uncomment to see without animation
        .frame(height: animatedContentHeight)
        .indexViewStyle(.page(backgroundDisplayMode: .always))
        .onChange(of: selectedTab) { newValue in
            print("now selected:", newValue)
            withAnimation { animatedContentHeight = selectedTab.contentHeight }
        }
    }
}

struct TestView1: View {
    var body: some View {
        Color.red
    }
}


struct TestView2: View {
    var body: some View {
        Color.black
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I wanted the tabview height to be dynamic. Lets say the I didn't know the height of view1 or view2. The answer u provided works if I know the height for view1 and view2.

Comment: @LuisRamirez Gotcha. Do you need the height to be able to change too? Like can Tabs expand and shrink at random? Or is height known during `onAppear`?

Comment: What do you mean at random?

Comment: I mean, does the Tab ever change height while you’re looking at it?

Comment: No don't think the tab will ever change height while looking at it